# How to add routes with the monologue gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing, monologue

I am using the [monologue gem](https://github.com/jipiboily/monologue) and trying to create an email list signup form on one of the monologue pages.  Here is the code:

```
<%= form_for EmailList.new, url: email_lists_path, remote: true, class: 'form-horizontal' do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :email, id: 'userid', class: 'form-control input-medium email-field', placeholder: 'email', required: "" %>
    <%= f.submit "Sign In", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
<% end %>
```

and here is how the route is defined when i run `rake routes`:

```
email_lists POST       /email_lists(.:format)                    email_lists#create
```

So it should be working but instead I get this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `email_lists_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fdddf519a40>:0x007fdde482bd78>
```

It has something to do with how the monologue engine is mounted:

```
mount Monologue::Engine, at: '/blog'
```

Any way, how do I add routes that work within the blog?

Comment: Try changing `email_lists_path` to `email_lists`

Comment: Thanks, tried that but has no effect.  I get the same error except is says "email_lists" instead of "email_lists_path"

Comment: I am fairly new to rails and I've never worked with monologue, but I find it a bit strange your `rake routes` would come out without `_path`. If I were you i'd submit an issue on their Github page.

Comment: I've never seen _path in rake routes. It's not supposed to have it there.  It purposefully does not include the last part because there are things other than _path such as _url that it can show.

Comment: @Philip7899 where is located that ERB file and where is defined the route? It looks like they are not in the same context...maybe? Is that repo public?